# How to "return" to a specific page with a tab in a Controller?

Tags: spring, jsp, controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/updateTask", method = RequestMethod.POST){
    ...
    return "updateContract";
}
```

How would I specify a page with a tab ? For example, what I need is "updatecontract#tab1". 
IF I specify that, it doesn't work.

Help!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use "redirect" in your return statement

Example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update/updateTask", method = RequestMethod.POST){
    ...
    return "redirect:updateContract#tab1";
}
```